# req.session is empty in POST route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookie-session

I am using passport.js google oAuth20 along with cookie-session middleware, but whenever i `console.log(req.session)` it is {} (empty), it only happens in POST route

Here is the route

```
  app.post("/addTodo", (req, res) => {
    console.log("POST", req.session);
    // UserSchema.findOne({ _id: req.session.passport.user }, function(err, res) {
    //   res.todos.push({ name: req.body.todo, isCompleted: false });
    //   res.save((err, value) => {});
    // });
    res.send("Add todo");
  });
```

Here is my passport strategy:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = mongoose.model("UserSchema");
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("serializeUser");
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    console.log("deserializeUser");
    done(err, user);
  });
});
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID:
        "hidden for security concerns",
      clientSecret: "hidden for security concerns",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback"
    },

    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

      if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
      }

      const user = await new User({
        googleId: profile.id,
        email: profile.emails[0].value
      }).save();
      done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

My middlewares in index.js are as follows:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: ["abc"]
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

basicRoutes(app);
authRoutes(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

I was having cors issue's so i installed this [cors plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), and i am having issues both when sending through client side and from postman as well.

Thanks in advance for your time and concern.

Comment: Why are you facing cors issues ? Seems like you are expecting cookies of other domain. `session` information is stored in cookie, and browser doesn't cookie of one domain to the other.

Comment: How can i know if i am expecting cookies of some other domain

Comment: You mentioned that you were having CORS issues.

Comment: Yeah and for that i am using that chrome plugin.